# Does \input really just include the file?

Tags: input

I have an issue with the `\input` command.

As it [is stated here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/250/11083), "it's equivalent to typing all the commands from filename.tex right into the current file where the \input line is."

I have the feeling that **this is not exactly the case**, at least in some situations, and I would like some clarifications.

Consider this MVCE (say, in a file `main.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenvir}{Hello}
\mycommand{World}
\end{myenvir}
\end{document}
```

Now the `mypackage.sty` file (stored in same folder):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[version 0.1]

\newenvironment{myenvir}[1]
{%
    \newcommand{\mycommand}[1]
    { test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1}
    \begin{center}
}
{\end{center}} 
\endinput
```

When compiling `main.tex`, this works fine, and produces.

```
test:command arg=World environment arg=Hello
```

But now, lets say for some reason (*), I want to store the command definition in a separate file. So I just change the sty file to:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[version 0.1]

\newenvironment{myenvir}[1]
{%
    \input{fcommand}
    \begin{center}
}
{\end{center}} 
\endinput
```

And store into a file `fcommand.tex` these two lines:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]
{ test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1}
```

Shouldn't that give **strictly the same result**?

But when compiling `main.tex` I get this error:

> You can't use `macro parameter character # in horizontal mode

and the output (pdf) file holds:

```
test:command arg=1 environment arg=World
```

**Question**: what is going on ? A far as I understand, there seems to be a problem with argument substitution when code is in a separate file. Thus my assumption that `\input` is not truly equivalent to having the code in same file.

I have also checked [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18017/), where the answer states to add `\unskip`. So I tried this:

```
\input{fcommand}\unskip%
```

and changed the command file content:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]
{ test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1}\endinput
```

But still got the same error.

Other related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/319512/11083

(*) On the reason to try this, this question is actually a follow up [on another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458080/) I am currently dealing with.

Comment: did you see the answer from Martin Scharrer and especially the 2nd comment.

Comment: By the way, [this minimal document](https://pastebin.com/RfVeY7qq) replicates your behaviour. For future reference, rather than saying I have `file1.tex` that looks like this, and `file2.tex` that looks like this, and I use them in `main.tex` in this way, try to provide a single, contained copy-and-paste example. I know it may not always be possible.

Comment: The issue here is that you're after an environment argument that `\mycommandA` knows nothing about. Is your main question that you want to use the argument of the environment (if there was one) in a command that you define inside the environment?

Comment: @Werner Yes, I understand you concern (not easy to get through the code when spread in the text). But I wasn't aware of the package filecontent. And given the case (several files involved), I couldn't really do it another way.

Comment: @albert Sorry, I have 4 linked questions, with multiple answers ;-) ! You mean the [second one here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32058/11083) ? About not using \include? Not sure it is related here...

Comment: No I meant the first (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include/250#250)

Comment: The answer of Martin Scharrer is just below it, I should have linked to the question not to the reference you gave,

Comment: @albert I read all the answers and all the comments on that page, sorry, I still don't see what you are trying to tell me. Maybe you could tell me what your point is?

Comment: @kebs: You didn't answer my question in the comment. Are you after a command that has access to the environment argument? If so, there are ways around using `##1` and `#1` the way you do.

Comment: @Werner Sorry, yes, I do need to have access to the environment argument (but I assumed this was clear from the code: `test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1` ?) Or maybe I don't understand what you question is ? What do you mean by "there are ways around using ..." ?

Comment: by the way the answer to your question in bold is essentially "no".  The replacement text of a definition is not interpreted at all at the point of definition so there is essentially no `\input`  there. It is interpreted at the point the definition is used, and there it does give the same error as if you have used the `##` forms inline.

Comment: Thanks @David, that is also the conclusion I have: in such a case \input'ing a file is not strictly equivalent to having the code "inside".

Comment: @kebs there is only an `\input`  when the command is used. Not at the point of definition, and if you use `##` at that point then you get the same error, so i would say that they are equivalent. Nothing special about input here, you can have any command `\foobar` in the definition and it does not even need to be defined, `\foobar` will only give an error if you use the environment and it is not defined at that point.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is not clear, the question is why it works without `\input` but it doesn't with it?

Comment: @touhami I'm not sure how else I can say it. I struggle to answer as I would never expect the `##` in the input file to work as the OP intended. But then I'm reading it as tex reads it, presumably kebs is reading it with a different expectation...

Comment: Correct, I assumed it worked just like the `#include` in C or C++ language, but it appears it is not the same (although maybe you can also have some oddities with  `#include`? can't be sure...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when TeX reads the environment command it detects where all the `#1` are, but the `\input` is not processed. When the environment is executed (that is, the underlying `\myenvir` command is expanded), all the `#1` seen previously are replaced by the argument `Hello`. So using

```
\begin{myenvir}{Hello}
\mycommand{World}
\end{myenvir}
```

is the same as (minus the comments)

```
% \begin{myenvir}{Hello}
\input{fcommand}
\begin{center}
% environment contents
\mycommand{World}
% \end{myenvir}
\end{center}
```

The `Hello` was lost because it wasn't used anywhere. *Now* the `\input` is expanded:

```
% \begin{myenvir}{Hello}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]
{ test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1}
\begin{center}
% environment contents
\mycommand{World}
% \end{myenvir}
\end{center}
```

Then, after the definition is done, the expansion of `\mycommand` yields:

```
% \begin{myenvir}{Hello}
% \newcommand{\mycommand}[1] %%% Already defined
% { test:command arg=##1 environment arg=#1}
\begin{center}
% environment contents
test:command arg=#1 environment arg=World
% \end{myenvir}
\end{center}
```

Ans now you're trying to write `#1` in the middle of the text, which raises the error:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
l.40 test:command arg=#
                       1 environment arg=World
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I'll need some time to get it all. You have any idea how I can solve the problem (i.e. make the trick work)?

Comment: @kebs Sorry, I tried, but I couldn't come up with anything clever. The only solution I can think about is to store the argument of the environment in a macro, and use that macro in the definition of `\mycommand`. Like this: https://pastebin.com/2c8DQNt7

Comment: @kebs just save the argument while it is in scope, if your environment does `\def\zzz{#1}` before the `\inut` then the commans defined in that file can use `\zzz` to get access to that argument, `Hello` in the example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Phelype, Thanks to both, I think you both describe the same workaround, I'll try that.